# Reduce memory usage in coreplot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

My core plot graph consumes lot of memory. It crashes when I am plotting graph into a large frame. Every time I am recreating the graph by releasing graph object and it's host view. 
Also tried to remove plots added to the graph,

```
    for(CPTPlot* plot in [graphByCorePlot_ allPlots]) {
        plot.dataSource = nil;
        plot.delegate = nil;
        [plot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, plot.cachedDataCount)];
        [graphByCorePlot_ removePlot:plot];
    }
```

Is it enough to release all the memory allocated by core plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of that should be necessary. You can update the graph by calling `-reloadData` on the graph to load new data for all plots. You can use the same method to update a single plot as well.

When you're done with the graph, remove it from the hosting view and release it if you have a retained reference to it.

If you're still having memory problems, use Instruments to check for leaks.